# Generic programming : error when trying to put values in an EnumMap

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, collections

I am using Java generic programming for creating an HashMap:

```
 Map< String, ? super TreeSet< MyObject>> myMap = new HashMap< String, TreeSet< MyObject>>();
```

However when I try to add something in `myMap`, I get an error.

```
Set< MyObject> mySet = new TreeSet< MyObject>();
myMap.put("toto", mySet);
```

The error is:

```
put(String, capture< ? super java.util.TreeSet< MyObject>>) in Map cannot be applied to (String, java.util.Set< MyObject>)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mySet` is declared to be of type `Set` while the map can only contain `TreeSet`s in the values. The compiler cannot guarantee that `mySet`, which is to be added, is not a `HashSet`, which can lead to a runtime exception. That's why it signals a compilation error.

You should program to the interface when declaring `TreeSet` as a type argument. In other words, you should use `Set` instead:

```
Map<String, ? super Set<MyObject>> myMap = new HashMap<String, Set<MyObject>>();
```

Unless you're certain that only `TreeSet`s are always used, in which case you can change the type of `mySet` to `TreeSet`:

```
// or
TreeSet<MyObject> mySet = new TreeSet<MyObject>();
```